# C# LINQ Any() Comparig two Lists

Tags: linq

I have two lists

`List<string> setA = new List<string>() {"cat", "dog", "elephant"};`

`List<string> setB = new List<string>() {"cat"};`

I have bool
`bool compare = setA.Any(x => x.Equals(setB.Select(y => y)));` which suppose to check for me if any string from setA eqauls string 'cat' from setB. it suppose to be 'true' but it isnt :/ (showing me as 'false')

What Im doing wrong?

Comment: bool compare = setA.Any(x => setB.Any(b => x.Equals(b)));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is wrong:

```
bool compare = setA.Any(x => x.Equals(setB.Select(y => y)));
```

This does following: checking if any strings in `setA` equal the `IEnumerable<string>` instance returned from `setB.Select(y => y)`. So you are basically comparing a string with a LINQ query which is never true.

This is the most efficient way to check if any string in A is in B:

```
bool compare = setA.Intersect(setB).Any();
```

You can also use this, which is less efficient if the lists are large;

```
bool compare = setA.Any(setB.Contains);
```

Comment: what if setA is typ classA and setB is typ classB where classA has classA.property1, classA.property2 and  classB has classB.property1. I want to compare classA.property1 with classB.property1 if they are equal or not (true or false)

Comment: @Slide: Then either `Select` this property(`setA.Select(x=>x.Property1).Any(setB.Select(x=>x.Property1).Contains);`) or implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<classA>` where this logic is in `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. You can use that comparer for many LINQ methods.

Comment: it works. thank you for your help.